# Vim CtrlP Plugin: Manually set root search directory?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have read through the docs but cannot figure out if this is possible.

I want to keep the default setting of `g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 2`, but I want the ability to manually override that for all buffers in the current window if I want.

Specifically, I want to issue a ctrlp command or change a ctrlp config variable that sets the root search directory, such that is uses that directory for all future searches, regardless of which buffer I'm in.

**Bonus Question**: Is it possible to set two root directories, so that it searches both of them and combines the results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

> let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
>
> 'c' - the directory of the current file.
>
> 'r' - the nearest ancestor that contains one of these directories or files: .git .hg .svn .bzr
>
> 'a' - like c, but only if the current working directory outside of CtrlP is not a direct ancestor of the directory of the current file.
>
> 0 or '' (empty string) - disable this feature.

Source: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim

Also, here: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/292 , the author has provided one way to set fullpath:

```
:CtrlP /var/www/myproject/bla/bla/theme
```

Comment: This has since been enhanced with the `'w'` option, which is brilliant (if you set vim working dir to above your repos, it lets you stay "outside" and search across all of them). Useful when you have many small repos (which is often the best way to be configuring large codebases using git)

Comment: Am not certain if this still works.
Steven's answer was what worked for me.
`let g:ctrlp_cmd='CtrlP :pwd'`

Answer (score 15):

I use:

```
let g:ctrlp_cmd='CtrlP :pwd'
```

this remap ctrlp commando to :ctrlp :pwd

Answer (score 9):

You can use the below in your vimrc

```
noremap <C-a> :CtrlP /yourdir/<CR>
```

whenever you press `ctrl+a` the ctrlp will take /yourdir/ as root directory

Comment: I find `noremap <C-a> :CtrlP ~<CR>` quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrlp triggers the search for current working directory.
So while you can set the default g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 2  , you can easily override for the current window by changing the pwd.
example

(by default)

`:pwd tmp/vim/usr`

and you want to change it to tmp just to

`:cd ../../`

and now run ctrlp